# send Viewport-Width in axios GET request

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, request

How I can  send axios request and put there the width of the viewport?

```
axios.get('https://ukrparts.com.ua/category/komplekt-stsepleniya/c-134/',{
    headers:{
        "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:102.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/102.0",
        "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
        "Width":1366,
        "Viewport-Width":1366
    }
})
.then(resp=>{
    let $ = cheerio.load(resp.data);
    $.html()
    let listPage = $('ul').html();
})
```

the response always returns me a mobile version site ((* but I need the desktop version.